# Is it possible to predict when Perl's decimal/float math will be wrong?

Tags: perl, math, binary, decimal, inexact-arithmetic

In one respect, I understand that Perl's floats are inexact binary representations, which causes Perl's math to sometimes be wrong.  What I don't understand, is why sometimes these floats seem to give exact answers, and other times, not.  **Is it possible to predict when Perl's float math will give the wrong (i.e. inexact answer)?**

For instance, in the below code, Perl's math is wrong 1 time when the subtraction is "16.12 - 15.13", wrong 2 times when the problem is "26.12 - 25.13", and wrong 20 times when the problem is "36.12 - 35.13".  Furthermore, for some reason, in all of the above mentioned test cases, the result of our subtraction problem (i.e. $subtraction_problem) starts out as being wrong, but will tend to become more correct, the more we add or subtract from it (with $x).  This makes no sense, why is it that the more we add to or subtract from our arithmetic problem, the more likely it becomes that the value is correct (i.e. exact)?

```
my $subtraction_problem = 16.12 - 15.13;
my $perl_math_failures = 0;
for (my $x = -25; $x< 25; $x++){
        my $result = $subtraction_problem +$x;
        print "$result\n";
        $perl_math_failures++ if length $result > 6;
}
print "There were $perl_math_failures perl math failures!\n";
```

Comment: Trying "use bignum" at the top of my script, which makes numbers that are Math::BigFloat objects solved this problem for me.

Comment: (Answering in a comment because question was closed as a duplicate.) Yes, it is possible to predict when floating-point anomalies will occur, because the IEEE floating-point representation is deterministic.

Comment: And, [Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) goes through the nitty-gritty of figuring out the errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of this is Perl specific. See [Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html):

> #### Rounding Error
>
> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, **given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly represented using that many bits.** Therefore the result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation. The section Relative Error and Ulps describes how it is measured.
>
> Since most floating-point calculations have rounding error anyway, does it matter if the basic arithmetic operations introduce a little bit more rounding error than necessary? That question is a main theme throughout this section. The section Guard Digits discusses guard digits, a means of reducing the error when subtracting two nearby numbers. Guard digits were considered sufficiently important by IBM that in 1968 it added a guard digit to the double precision format in the System/360 architecture (single precision already had a guard digit), and retrofitted all existing machines in the field. Two examples are given to illustrate the utility of guard digits.
>
> The IEEE standard goes further than just requiring the use of a guard digit. It gives an algorithm for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and square root, and requires that implementations produce the same result as that algorithm. Thus, when a program is moved from one machine to another, the results of the basic operations will be the same in every bit if both machines support the IEEE standard. This greatly simplifies the porting of programs. Other uses of this precise specification are given in Exactly Rounded Operations.

Comment: The point made there, though, is true even if we're dealing with, say, using a decimal number format to represent decimal numbers that exceed that format's precision.  In this case, assuming the decimal number is finite precision, all that's needed is to raise the precision of the decimal number format. The question, in contrast, is saying that some x-ary numbers with a finite precision can't be represented using a y-ary format of any finite precision (which will be the case if x is 10 and y is 2).

Comment: Actually, this question is interesting because the problem only visible with one specific value, and cannot be observed if one uses C's or Perl's `printf` ... Only if you print the result of a particular operation using Perl's `print` can the consequences of 0.1 not being exactly representable, and the relative magnitudes of the operands becomes a visible issue. The quotation in my answer is meant to be a lead-in to direct the reader to a detailed discussion of floating point rather than re-hashing everything here.